# Excel for Mac Version 16.42, Setting a cell value gives a 1004: application error (nothing more specific)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a spreadsheet and I am scraping some information from a HTTP call, and when I run the following code, it always errors out with 1004: Application Error

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   
   Set ws = Worksheets("Distances")
   
   Rem ws.Activate

   Dim s As String

   For y = 34 To MaxPair
        If (ws.Cells(y, 1) = vbNullString) Then

           On Error GoTo helpme

            ws.Cells(y, 1).Value = c1 -- error happens on this line

            Exit Sub
        End If
        
     Next y
     Exit Sub
helpme:
     MsgBox ("" & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description)
```

the value C1 = "LHR" and y = 142.  I've tried like 40 different things and nothing seems to work.  This is mind boggling as updating a cells value is one of the most basic things in Excel.

Comment: Is the ) after vbnullstring intentional?

Comment: Yes, it belong the the ( just after `If`

Comment: It's a programmatically neutral effect on the subsequent code

Comment: Are you getting the same error when doing `ws.Cells(142, 1).Value = "LHR"`, just after the `ws.Activate` line?

Comment: Yes, same error when I move the On Error above it and then execute it with 100% literals.

Comment: you are definitely in the right workbook?

Comment: Yes, the values found while iterating through sheet looking for the vbnull, show the existing values.